# Joins in mysql what to do

Tags: mysql, get, opencart

Well I wrote a query and get an error:

> Column 'product_id' in field list is ambiguous
>   Error No: 1052

I need to select the same id from 2 tables and compare them by price here is query I wrote:

```
$product_sql_test1 = $this->db->query("SELECT `product_id` and 'price'    FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category`INNER JOIN (oc_product)ON oc_product.product_id=prdoduct_to_category.product_id WHERE product_to_category.id=product.id and  price >150 and `category_id`='".$product_info['related_kv4nt_id_1']."'  GROUP BY `product_id` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,10");
```

Where could be an error and how to fix it? Sorry if the question is too simple.

Comment: `product_id` exists in multiple joined tables and MySQL doesn't know which one you mean! Use `table_or_alias_name.product_id` to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

You have to mention the table name while selecting  the product_id because many tables have this column and mysql is confused to select the column from which table

```
$product_sql_test1 = $this->db->query("SELECT oc_product.`product_id` and 'price'    
FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category`INNER JOIN (oc_product)ON 
oc_product.product_id=prdoduct_to_category.product_id WHERE product_to_category.id=product.id and  price >150 and prdoduct_to_category.`category_id`='".$product_info['related_kv4nt_id_1']."' 
GROUP BY oc_product.`product_id` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,10");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the full name:

```
Tablename.ColumnName
```

For Example in the GROUP BY part it is not clear which `product_id` you mean.

Answer (score 0):

**Use an Alias name for tables and columns.**

Access it like `oc.product_id` (for column) and `oc_product oc`(for table)

Answer (score 0):

Both in your `Select` and your `Group By`, you need to `use your alias table names along with your column names` because the same column is present in multiple tables and thus there's a confusion as to which one to use for the result.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is

```
$product_sql_test1 = $this->db->query("SELECT `p`.`product_id`, `p`.`price` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category` `p2c` LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "product` `p` ON `p`.`product_id` = `p2c`.`product_id` WHERE `p`.`price` > 150 and `p2c`.`category_id`='" . (int) $product_info['related_kv4nt_id_1'] . "' GROUP BY `p`.`product_id` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,10");
```

You should also consider formatting your SQL to make it easier to read as well